# Converting decimal number to hexadecimal number using recursive method

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert decimal to hexadecimal. I have found many codes online. I used

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

but my instructor told me I can't use any of those, just use recursive method. I am new to programming and little confused about recursive method.

I did find other methods to convert it, I am using below method, and I used switch statement to change numbers to letters. Program works fine. But not sure if it is recursive method? Can someone let me know if it is recursive method, if not help me understand how recursive method work.

```
static void HexadecimalConversion(int decimals)
{
    if (decimals == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        int hexadecimals = decimals % 16;
        decimals = decimals / 16;
        HexadecimalConversion(decimals);
```

Comment: It is recursive (calling itself) but `void` won't let you build up a result.

Comment: Change the return type to `string` and try again. Oh, and by convention a method like this should have a name starting with a verb, so something more like `string ConvertToHex(int number)` would be a better signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most recursive problems, you have 1 or 2 special cases and a general case. For this problem there are 3 cases:

- **Special Case #1.** The value to be converted is 0.
- **The General Case.** The value to be converted is greater than 0.
- **The Terminating Case.** When the value to be converted is finally decremented to 0.

You need to distinguish between the two 'zero' conditions, lest you always append a trailing zero to the result, so...you need a 2-layered approach, something like this:

```
static string Int2Hex( int value )
{
  if ( value <  0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value") ;
  if ( value == 0 ) return "0" ;

  string result = ToHex( (uint) value ).ToString() ;
  return result ;
}

static StringBuilder ToHex ( uint value )
{
  StringBuilder buffer ;
  if ( value <= 0 )
  {
    buffer = new StringBuilder() ;
  }
  else
  {
    buffer = ToHex( value / 16 ).Append( "0123456789ABCDEF"[ (int)(value % 16 ) ] ) ;
  }
  return buffer ;
}
```

Comment: `Substring` could be replaced with `"0123456789ABCDEF"[value % 16]`

Comment: Not without a compile error. An expression like `"01234"[2]` yields a char, so you'd have the equivalent of `"some-string" + '2'`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312: polished the code a little, you might like it :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation

```
 public void ConvertToHexa(int number)
        {
            if (number == 0)
                return;
            ConvertToHexa(number / 16);
            var remainder = number % 16;
            Console.Write(remainder >= 10 ? ((char)(remainder - 10 + 'A')).ToString() : remainder.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: If you could make it return the result rather than writing to the console I'd like the answer.

Comment: BTW, `ConvertToHexa(200)` produces `678`. Something's wrong.

Comment: fixed the issue

Comment: `ConvertToHexa(202)` now produces `C10`. It should be `CA`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation:

```
public string ConvertToHexa(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return String.Empty;
    var head = ConvertToHexa(number / 16);
    var remainder = number % 16;
    var tail = (char)(remainder + (remainder >= 10 ? 'A' - 10 : '0'));
    return head + tail;
}
```

`Console.WriteLine(ConvertToHexa(202))` gives `"CA"` (which is correct).